# Facebook React.js : How to use components directly inside html as normal tags without mounting?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, reactjs

I am to create my `custom tag` :

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var TodoList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(itemText) {
      return <li>{itemText}</li>;
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
  }
});
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], text: ''};
  },
  onChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.text]);
    var nextText = '';
    this.setState({items: nextItems, text: nextText});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.text} />
          <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**Without mounting from JSX**

```
// React.renderComponent(<TodoApp />, document.body);
```

I intend to use it inside my `HTML` templates instead :

```
<div class="container">
    <TodoApp />    <!-- Doesn't work -->
</div>
```

Is it possible to use the `react` component tags directly inside html templates. Since it seems really inconvenient to mount it every-time from `JSX`/`JS` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. For one exploration into the possibilities here, see [Custom Components: React & x-tags](http://blog.vjeux.com/2013/javascript/custom-components-react-x-tags.html), but there isn't any supported way to do this.

Having to render the component from JS likely isn't too different from whatever JS you're currently using to attach events, etc. If your entire app can be rendered by one top-level React component (as is true for TodoApp) then you'll only need a single call to renderComponent.

Comment: I was wondering how legible will the code be in case its just not react. May be an existing app with some components done by `react` with empty holes in your markup which somehow gets filled on the runtime. Seems like sought going against the philosophy of being `declarative`. 

Anyways, `no` is also an answer at least I can stop looking.

Comment: Any tips for managing the mounting well incase its just not a `react.js` application ?